# C++: BOOST-ASIO async_read_some does not return number of packet bytes?

Tags: c++, size, byte, boost-asio, packet

I tried using following code to read the number of available bytes in the socket (on the server side) and the variable `packet_bytes` does not do anything. I was expecting the number of bytes used by the packet to be read into `packet_bytes` but that doesn't seem to work.

```
std::size_t packet_bytes = 0;

socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            packet_bytes));
```

I also tried `std::size_t packet_bytes = socket_.available();` and that didn't return anything either. This is the [entire code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `packet_bytes` argument in the `bind` call should also be a placeholder:

```
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
    boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Then in your handler function that argument will be the amount of bytes read.

See e.g. the example in the [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html).

Comment: Isn't that parameter used for getting the bytes in the socket?

Comment: How do I create the handler function though?

Comment: @lost_with_coding Okay, after rereading your question, it seems you want to know the number of bytes that _can_ be read, i.e. the number of bytes in the receive buffer, and not the number of bytes you just received. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, how do I get the number of bytes for the packet received by the server?

Comment: No, the number of bytes received not the number of a bytes that can be read. Aren't they the same though.

Comment: basically the method similar to this `size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);`

Comment: @lost_with_coding Then that's what my `async_read_some` does. The second argument to your handler will be the amount of data received.

Comment: But the manual you showed doesn't explain how to use the handler or even create one. I guess its an object?

Comment: @lost_with_coding If you look at the last example in the linked to manual page, it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Does the function `void my_class::read_handler` get called automatically when `async_read_some` is invoked ?

Comment: @lost_with_coding Yes it gets called automatically, but probably not when `async_read_some` is invoked, but when data has been received (which might be any time).

Comment: I tried running that function in the code and sent a packet but it didn't do anything. I pasted `void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
        std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
  }` into the code?

Comment: @lost_with_coding And you have the `io_service` running?

Comment: Yup just like in the code for the async server `session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)`

Comment: @lost_with_coding You do know that the `io_service` object contains the actual event loop that will call your async handlers? You should either call its [`poll`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll.html) function at regular intervals, or let it do it automatically with the [`run`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) function.

Comment: I tried placing `io_service.run();` into the constructor for the `session` class but that caused the server to hang?

Comment: The `run` function goes into an infinite loop polling and dispatching events. You should call it _after_ everything is set up. See how their [async server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) does it.

Comment: Right, it turns out I already have it running, I'm already using the asyn server example. Thats the code I pasted `void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) { std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl; }` into